# State tax withholding election

Tags: united-states, taxes, state-income-tax, new-york, connecticut

I live in Connecticut but work in New York. My employer wants to know what state I wish to be "taxed in". I understand that CT gives a credit for taxes paid in NY. Which state should I elect to have my payroll withholdings paid to?